# Using count function to count records from two tables and returns the same even if count is zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Employee and Department

- Fields of Employee : id, name, dept_id
- Fields of Department: dept_id, name

I need a query which fetches me department name and number of employees per department along with it, even if number of employees for a department is zero.

I tried the query below, but it returns only those departments which have number of employees more than zero.

```
select d.name, count(e.id) as "Number of employees per department" 
from department d, employee e 
where d.DEPT_ID=e.DEPT_ID 
group by d.name 
order by count(e.id) desc;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query gives the desired result.

SELECT DEPARTMENT.NAME,COUNT(EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID) 
FROM DEPARTMENT LEFT OUTER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID = DEPARTMENT.DEPT_ID GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.NAME ;

Answer (score 1):

You need to outer join your tables.

```
FROM department d 
   LEFT JOIN employee e 
   ON d.DEPT_ID=e.DEPT_ID
```

Comment: Not explicitly. That's why he's not seeing the Departments that have no matches in the Employee table, they fail the where clause. By using the left join, it will return all the departments. (Also I might be wrong on the specific details, been in Oracle land for too long)

Comment: Your answer explanation is wrong. Just cause it's not a explicit JOIN won't be a issue. Issue is he is doing a `inner join`

Comment: As per the suggestions above, I tried the following queries:                                       Query 1: select d.name, e.name FROM department d 
   LEFT JOIN employee e 
   ON d.DEPT_ID=e.DEPT_ID                                                                           Output: It returns department name and the employee working for that department. It displays null in field of employee name where department has no employee.

Comment: Query 2: select d.name, count(e.id) FROM department d 
   LEFT JOIN employee e 
   ON d.DEPT_ID=e.DEPT_ID                                                                              
Output: It returns the 1st department name and total number of employees in the employee table.